# How Can I obtain HAC standard errors for my VAR model?

Tags: r

I've seen similar questions to this but the solutions don't seem to apply to my situation.

Anyway, my data looks like this. All variables are I(0) after first differencing.

```
   diff.data.gdpg. diff.data.narrowmg. diff.data.inf. diff.data.stir. diff.data.xrusd.
1     -0.51271298           -1.823265     -1.6304108      -1.0116667       -1.1520946
2     -0.04111672            2.799135     -0.3754515      -0.8033333       -3.8242471
3     -1.27394110            1.171467     -1.0167953      -0.7600000       -0.3483001
4     -1.23568342            3.327228     -0.6832069      -0.9600000       -1.1126535
5      2.92195504            4.291975      0.8145149      -0.7100000        0.4041784
6      1.79054994            2.522487      0.9598156       0.6266667        0.3260302
```

( I know that it is technically not advised to first difference when using VAR but I'm not concerned with forecasting here. I just want to get an idea of the relationships across these variables).

Anyway, I use the vars package and run my VAR. I save the lmobject I would like to get the standard errors of to another variable.

```
varmodel <- VAR(newdata, p = 4, type = "const")
lmobject <- varmodel$varresult$diff.data.stir.
```

Finally, I use call vcovHAC on the object.

```
vcovHAC(lmobject)
```

which gives me the following error

```
Error in bread. %*% meat. : non-conformable arguments
```

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late, but I will answer this anyway in case anybody else searches for the same problem. I guess your problem here was having a `varest` object after estimating your model with the `VAR()` function. For `vcovHAC()` no varest object is okay. While for `vcovHC` it is. If you want to get your HAC covariance matrix you should estimate your VAR Model with `dynlm()` for example. The `lm object` is okay for `vcovHAC`.